# clang armv7 calls wrong symbol on inline defined constructor in return statement

Tags: c++, android-ndk, clang++, armv7

While working on a JNI library for android I stumbled upon a problem that I can reproduce with clang from NDK r19b and the following MWE:

```
void firstFunctionSymbol() {}

template <class Y>
class T {
public:
        T(Y){};
};

T<int> test() {
        return {1};
}

int main(){
        return 0;
}
```

When compiling and inspecting this with:

```
$ android-ndk-r19b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/\
armv7a-linux-androideabi26-clang++ -g -c main.cpp -o main.o
$ android-ndk-r19b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/\
linux-x86_64/arm-linux-androideabi/bin/objdump -DS main.o --demangle
```

I get the following output:

```
00000000 <firstFunctionSymbol()>:
void firstFunctionSymbol() {}
   0:   e12fff1e        bx      lr

00000004 <test()>:
class T {
public:
        T(Y){};
};

T<int> test() {
   4:   e92d4800        push    {fp, lr}
   8:   e1a0b00d        mov     fp, sp
   c:   e24dd008        sub     sp, sp, #8
        return {1};
  10:   e28d0004        add     r0, sp, #4
  14:   e3001001        movw    r1, #1
  18:   ebfffffe        bl      0 <firstFunctionSymbol()>
  1c:   e58d0000        str     r0, [sp]
  20:   e1a0d00b        mov     sp, fp
  24:   e8bd8800        pop     {fp, pc}
```

Note how line 18 refers to firstFunctionSymbol instead of the expected `T<int>(int)`.

Am I doing something wrong or is clang failing me here?

Please note:

- this is not a problem on GCC for arm or clang on x86
- this problem only occurs when `T(Y){}` is a function that should be inlined. E.g. by defining `extern template class T<int>;` before the function, the symbol points to the right point.

Comment: Is it still incorrect after linking?

Comment: @Michael I am not sure how to test this. I don't know how to link my MWE (due to missing built in symbols) and the original code crashes on the device (probably due to this error).

Comment: Well, I'm asking because that 0 looks like it could be a placeholder for something that will be resolved at link time. Have you tried inspecting your actual library with objdump?

Comment: @Michael I will try but the final library is stripped into oblivion so I am having trouble locating this code.

Comment: @Michael thanks for the pointer. It seems that really is not the problem and my original code is crashing for some other reason. I just saw the wonky reference and focused to much on that.